# Java finding first & last letter. Last not working

Tags: java

My `char lastLetter` line is not working. Any help on this will be useful.

```
for (int k=0; k<userInput.length; k++)
{      
    char firstLetter = userInput[k].charAt(0);
    char lastLetter = userInput[k].charAt(userInput[k].lenght-1);

    System.out.print(userInput[k] +" First Letter "+ firstLetter); 
    System.out.print(userInput[k] +" Last letter " + lastLetter);

    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Comment: what exactly is not working?  BTW, this doesn't compile.  You misspelled `length`.

Comment: userInput is an array of String? And you are trying to get the last character of each string in the array?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by use of `.charAt(int)`, `userInput` is most likely an array of Strings

In this case, Strings do not have a length [field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#field.summary), but they do have a [length method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length--)

```
char lastLetter = userInput[k].charAt(userInput[k].length() - 1);
```